# printf in macro in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have a macro as such

```
#define PTF(A,y)    fprintf(file,"%s",A,y);printf("%s %d",A,y);
```

so that it will print to file and console
so for example i call this macro function

```
int y=9;
PTF("\nRound %d \n",y);
```

in a way I need the y=9 to be shown as part of the argument A so my fprintf in file will look like below

```
Round 9
```

because I have a lot of changes to make if I were to change this, hence hoping for an easy way out =)

Comment: in the fprintf function, it will print as "Round %d" instead. so i am wondering if there is any way to recognize the y to be shown in the fprintf

Comment: This is tangential to your question, but think about what would happen if someone were to call your macro like so: `if (cond) PTF("%d", y);`, where `cond` is some condition (it doesn't matter what it is).

Comment: @aix: That's why you **always** should use curly braces with `if`, `for` etc.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck, aix is entirely correct, it is really bad style to have unprotected `;` inside a macro. Macros that change flowcontrol should indicate that fact clearly in their name.

Comment: @Jens: It is also bad style to use a variable twice in the same macro. But you are correct, the two statements should be enclosed by curly braces.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck, curly braces are not enough, because they still could change control flow. The commonly used technique for that is to use `do { .... } while (0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

`#define PTF(A,y)    fprintf(file,"%s",A,y);printf("%s %d",A,y);`

to

`#define PTF(A,y)    fprintf(file,A,y);printf("%s %d",A,y);`

Note:

`PTF("Round %d",9);` will have fprint write `Round 9` to the file but printf will still show `Round %d 9`.

You'll also have to make sure you only specify one specifier to fprintf

Answer (score 3):

Macros are the wrong way to do this; especially in this construction, you'll run into about every macro pitfall there is. Imagine:

```
if(condition)
    PTF("%s", foo);
```

Simply write a variadic function:

```
void
ptf(char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    vprintf(fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    vfprintf(file, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work ->

```
#define PTF(A,...) fprintf(file,A,##__VA_ARGS__); printf(A,##__VA_ARGS__);

int y = 9;
PTF("\nRound %d \n",y);
```

Variadic Macros link -
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Unix (BSD/Linux/Solaris/etc.), maybe it's easier to use **[tee](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tee)** for that.

Comment: what if `file` has to change during the execution of the program? I don't see `tee` as a solution. The question is on how to write macros, not on how to split the output.

Comment: I said "maybe". There're lot of cases when we coding hard instead of using something already exist.

Answer (score 0):

The common idiom is to use `do { ... } while (0)` (some compilers will generate a warning for this) or the comma operator `,` and enclose your statements in parenthesis (but you can't use and control flow statement).

If you can rely on having a modern compiler (e.g. GCC 3+), you may use variadic macros to define a macro so that is similar to a regular `printf`.

I would go for something like:

```
#define PTF(...) (fprintf(file,__VA_ARGS__),printf(__VA_ARGS__))
```

so that `PTF("Round %d",y)` will print `Round 9` (assuming y=9) both on `file` and on `stdout`.

The usual caveat on side-effects in macros apply: never, never use `PTF("%d",y++)`.